# Ubuntu WiFi internet connection lost after connecting to raspberry Zero by USB port

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I have connected to Raspberry Zero following [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98790/raspberry-pi-zero-internet-connection-through-usb-for-linux-os/109685#109685). Now I have these settings:

[image]

And `/etc/network/interfaces` contains:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

    allow-hotplug enp0s20f0u2
    auto enp0s20f0u2
```

I also ran these commands:

```
sudo ifconfig enp0s20f0u2 192.168.7.1
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface wlp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface enp0s20f0u2 -j ACCEP
```

but I had this problem even before running them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it is working by running the :

`sudo nm-connection-editor`
and change the Ethernet of that usb connection to the correct IP Address, which is here **192.168.7.1** but it could be settled to others by your setting of /etc/network/interfaces file at raspberry SD card. and selecting the method to :

**share to other computers** 
like this:
[image]

also select the current device like this:

[image]

also you need to run this command because if don't of that you only have connection to the modem IP (192.168.1.1) and i don't know why this problem exist and why only can connect to local IP and not internet ( cold you say why?!!)

```
sudo dhclient  -r wlp2s0 #enp1s0
sudo dhclient wlp2s0 #enp1s0
```

Thanks.